# celery Flower not showing some workers?

Tags: python, django, celery, flower

Flower 1.0 is not showing some worker but flower 0.7 is showing the same worker as active.Strange?
I can see that celery is also showing the worker as active from control stats.

Answer (score 1):

You now need to pass the param refresh=True otherwise you may be reading a stale cache.

curl  -X GET http://localhost:5555/api/workers?refresh=True | json_pp